# SSRS parameter display

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using `State` as parameter. I have 10 states in my data. And I am showing which state user selected in the report. And I am using `Join(Parameters!State.Label, ", ")` to show what state user selected.

This is working as it is expected. But if user selected all states then I need to show just "All States" instead of showing names of all states.

Thanks in advance

This is what I am using to show state name from parameter list.

```
=Join(Parameters!State.Label, ", ")
```

Comment: I got to solve this myself with below code =IIF(
     Parameters!State.Count = countrows("YourDataset"),
     "All",
     Join(Parameters!State.Label,", ")
 )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got to solve this myself with below code =IIF( Parameters!State.Count = countrows("YourDataset"), "All", Join(Parameters!State.Label,", ") )